# Anyone recognize this toslink connector brand?

Tags: identification, connector, toslink

Anyone repaired the little plastic door of a toslink/adat port?
Anyone recognize this toslink connector brand?
It has a S logo on top.
Before i start to desolder and replace the whole port, i was thinking maybe i can buy another connector and just swap the little door. I take care of all my gear but theses doors are so fragile

You can see it on this picture, its black and gray contour:

[image: https://ibb.co/f49Vffn]

Comment: Please add links to the part you are describing and place a red circle on the image so we know what you are referring to.

Comment: ok i edited the post, here is the same picture with a blue circle to show you which one it is. I dont have a part number or any link, that's my question, i want to know what brand or model it is and if anyone has tips on how to replace the door only. https://ibb.co/f49Vffn

Comment: anyone have any idea?